# Should one generate a unique id for each row in a database table that otherwise has no unique keys?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, primary-key, relational-database

I'm designing a MySQL database for a startup working with patient medical records. I have several tables that can have no unique keys: medical conditions, allergies, family history, etc. For example the `medications` table might have fields `patient_id`, `med_name`, `usage_dates`, `dosage`, `reason`, etc. The only guaranteed unique key is all of the fields together.

A web application can easily retrieve this data for a given patient by selecting for `patient_id`, but unless it is possible to save pointers to rows inside a database with multiple users, it strikes me as a clumsy system for editing or deleting rows in this table. The DBMS would have to select for each field's value in order to find the correct row. From what (little) I know about databases, I imagine this could be inefficient in a large database.

Would it be more efficient to create a new field with an ID number to function as a primary key in each of these tables, or is the DBMS way smarter than me and this is totally unnecessary?

Comment: Are you serious? With the greatest respect, you say you know only a "little" about databases and yet you are designing a database for patient medical records!

Comment: Yes! Well. The medical records are only a small part of what we're doing right now. Our startup (developing a medical device) is only four people at the moment and I'm the computer guy. We just need a database up and running enough to communicate with our prototypes - down the line we will hire people with the specializations we need. While I'm doing this, though, I'm taking the opportunity to learn as much as possible, hence my question about something that isn't so critical at this stage.

Comment: "Can have no unique keys" and "the only guaranteed unique key is all of the fields together" mean completely opposite things. Do you get that?  It seems like the key for your medications table might be {patient_id, med_name, start_date}. In any case, patient_id should be pretty selective, so performance with many patients and many meds  should be fine. Prototype and test.

Comment: Absolutely - badly worded, I should have said "can have no unique keys except all of the fields together." Since patient_id is going to very selective you're right that performance will be fine. I think I will, however, go for a surrogate key as it might make the code slightly easier to write than using a composite primary key. Thanks for all the input everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always add a simple numeric primary key (e.g. mysql auto_increment) so you DO end up with a unique identifier for each row. Composite primary keys are a serious pain if you have to use the table in a foreign key relationship, forcing you to list each of the primary key's component's field's in all joins/FK specifications. By comparison, adding a simple int primary key reduces you to carrying that ONE field around for the FK/join relationships.

I'd suggest something along the lines of:

```
patients (id, name, ....)
meds (id, brand, name, ...)
patient_meds (patient_id, med_id, dosage, ...)
```

Comment: +1 This is how I would definitely do it, assuming that there could possibly be more information about each type of med, other than just "name".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this would be called a "synthetic key", and I would certainly add one, probably as just an AUTO_INCREMENT field.  It will make updates a lot simpler (and faster) if you do.

Answer (score 1):

I think an ID field is almost always a good idea. It guarantees one column that you can use to uniquely identify one row in your database. I also think it's a good idea because it can make your queries faster because the primary key of a table is indexed, so if you select based on the unique ID column, MySQL doesn't have to search through all the rows to find the one you're looking for. It knows exactly where to go and you queries will run much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a "best practice".  In addition to updates, it makes deletes and certain joins much faster.

Many third party tools depend on a unique primary key.